# Looking for books on Datastructures(Tree)

Tags: c#, java, tree

Does anyone know a good book on datastructures where tree's are explained in depth. Language C# or Java.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Trees explained in depth. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" by Robert Lafore is a good introductory book to the subject, very worth reading.

link : http://www.algolist.net/Books/0672324539

Worth a buy.Please read it incase you need some serious stuff about data structures and algorithms in Java.

Comment: please upvote in case you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of books out there on data structures but if you really want to know tree structures I recommend you check out [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504).

I know you asked for C#/Java but Tree structures are much more elegantly explained in an FP language.

Comment: Really?  This book is going to be totally out of most peoples depth - and what is the point in learning about functional data structures when you are programming in C# / Java?

Comment: @James Gaunt FP made me a better Java programmer. And if I recall doesn't C# use a lot FP constructs these days like LINQ? ... kind of funny cause you just asked a question on LINQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915127/can-a-linq-to-sql-iqueryable-be-unexpectedly-evaluated

Comment: Of course FP has it's place - I just think to recommend this book as a way of learning about trees is a bit extreme.  Most of this book isn't about trees, and the parts that are wouldn't generally concern even a functional programmer working in the real world, it's really a maths text - it's about mathematically proving the properties of the data structures.  A working programmer (FP or otherwise) probably isn't interested.  Just don't want the chap to waste his money is all.